# Which Claims Are Alledged To Be Infringed By Facebook Causing Rembrandt Social Media To Sue For Infringement?

Tags: us6415316, us6289362

Quite confused as to which claims might be violated by Facebook and AddThis.com, causing them to get sued last month. Reference: http://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/fish--richardson-files-patent-infringement-lawsuit-for-rembrandt-social-media-in-virginia-against-facebook-add-this-inc-189859931.html

Comment: The '316 patent (and one of its claims) has previously been discussed [here](http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/3316/would-this-given-the-global-usage-of-diaries-on-both-big-and-small-websites-st)... you might find some hints there.

Answer (score 2):

*Rembrandt Social Media, LP v. Facebook, Inc. et al* (Case No. 1:13-cv-00158) 
was filed 2/4/13 in the Eastern District of Virginia.  It has been assigned to Judge T. S. Ellis.

In the complaint, the plaintiff alleges infringement of independent claims 1, 6, 17, 28, and 39 of the '316 patent and claim 7 of the '372 patent.